# junit couldn't load the value in resource folder

Tags: java, junit-runner

I am using MockitoJUnit library to test my controller. there are some variables which are declared as:

```
@Value("${mine.port}")
private Integer port;
```

when I run my test, it could not find the value mine.port in the resource folder as properties file. My controller is no problem to run, but the port number is null when I run my contoller junit test.

I used below annotation on my class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = myControl.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

I used below method in my junit test

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(myController)
            .build();
}
@Test
public void getName() throws Exception {
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = 
MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/service")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn(); }
```

I am confused, does anyone know if I am missing some settings? thx!

Comment: Is the spring context being loaded with that config?

Comment: have you tried to add `@TestPropertySource`?

Comment: How do you run your tests? Do you use build automation tool (maven, gradle..)?

Answer (score 2):

No one of the specified annotations will start a Spring container :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = myControl.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

To write a test slice focused on the controller  don't use a Mockito runner : `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` otherwise you could not start a Spring container.  `MockitoJUnitRunner` is for unit tests, not integration tests.
To know when and how to write unit and integration tests with Spring Boot you could read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789880/how-to-test-a-component-bean-in-spring-boot).

Instead of, use the `@WebMvcTest` annotation with a Spring runner such as :

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class WebLayerTest {
   ...
}
```

You can rely on this [Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) to have more details.

Comment: I used the springRunner also, it still shows the same problem

Comment: you don't have to use the springRunner also, you have to use only it. A single runner can be used to launch JUnit 4 tests.