# How to mock a DataSource in Junit 5 + Mockito 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have a legacy DAO class need to be tested with Junit5 + Mockito5 (No PowerMock is allowed). No matter how I write the test cases, the Datasource value is always null. I am expecting the Datasource should be a mock value that I assign or inject. I read many questions/articles in stackoverflow, but I have not found any straightforward solutions. Please help.

factory.getBean() will always return null for ds in the unit test. So ds.getConnection() will fail with NullPointerException. My object is to somehow inject a DataSource mock to DAO class to allow ds.getConnection() to return a mock Connection. So far I have tried to mock XmlBeanFactory class constructor, hoping when the factory calls getBean(), it will return a mock DataSource. Also I have tried to use Reflection to inject a mock DataSource. None of the above worked. I have read quite a few threads, but the more I read the more confused I am. Please advise.

```
.
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
.
.
public class DAO {
  private static DataSource ds;

  public static void getDataSource() throws Exception {
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("sample.xml");
    XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
    ds = (DataSource) factory.getBean("dataSourceString");
  }

  public static List getData(String input) {
    Connection con = null;
    getDataSource();
    con = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from sometable");
    .
    .
  }
}


class DAOTest {
  @Test
  void testGetData() {
    try (MockedConstruction<XmlBeanFactory> mock = mockConstruction(XmlBeanFactory.class) {
      DataSource mockDataSource = mock(DataSource.class);
      Connection mockConn = mock(Connection.class);

      DAO dao = new DAO();

      //attempt 1: try to mock construction for XmlBeanFactory, then return a mock DataSource. Error is IndexOutOfBoundsException
      XmlBeanFactory mockFactory = mock.constructed().get(0);
      when(mockFactory.getBean(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockDataSource);

      //attempt 2: try to use Reflect to inject the mockDataSource to the class. Error is NullPointerException: ds is null
      Field parentService = dao.getClass().getDeclaredField("ds");
      parentService.setAccessible(true);
      parentService.set(dao, mockDataSource);
      when(mockDataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConn);
      DAO.getData("some_input_data");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Design your classes to be testable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test a component / bean in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789880/how-to-test-a-component-bean-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Thank you all for the advices. I read the links suggested. Eventually I have the code below to get it work:
  @Test
  void testGetData() {
  DataSource ds = mock(DataSource.class);
  try (MockedConstruction<XmlBeanFactory> mockXmlBeanFactoryList = mockConstruction(XmlBeanFactory.class,
   (mock, context) -> {
    when(mock.getBean(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(ds);
   })) {

   DAO.getData("some_input_data");
   assertEquals(1, mockXmlBeanFactoryList.constructed().size());
   assertEquals(ds, DAO.dataSource);
  }
}